# How to use local variables with indices in a Mathematica Block environment?

Tags: scoping, variable-definitions

I have the following code:

```
Subscript[f, i_][x_] := Block[{a},
  Subscript[a, i] = 3 x;
  Subscript[a, 1]
]
```

If I evaluate for example `Subscript[f,1][2]`, it evaluates to `6`. After that asking what `Subscript[a,1]` is also gives me six. However, I want `a` to be a local variable.

My question: how can I define a local variable while using indices...?

**Note**: the original post mentioned that evaluating `Subscript[f,1][2] = 6` would lead to the described behaviour, which just isn't true. A reasonable guess is that this was ment to mean that `Subscript[f,1][2]` was to be evaluated and it would evaluate to `6` (which it does). After that  `Subscript[a,1]` will evaluate to `6` as reported.

Comment: Hello Bee, and welcome to math.SE. I think your question is better suited to the mathematica.SE site, so I'm going to migrate it there. There will be a link that appears below the question here that you can follow to the new location of your question. If you need help associating an account on mathematica.SE, you can flag your question for moderator attention, and someone over there will help out.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. Does this behave this way on a fresh Mathematica session?

Comment: @Bee: are you following this and the discussion to one of the answers? I'd suggest you have a look at my edit to your question and see if you think this makes sense.

Comment: @AlbertRetey [Bee](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/28403/bee) is unregistered on [Mathematics.se], and not at all here. So, it is likely that she is not following this. Do as you will, then.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that the definition which makes `Subscript[a,i]` evaluate to `6` is stored in the `DownValues` of `Subscript`. The down values of `Subscript` don't care about the blocking of `a` and will still exist when `Block` exits. You can check that by evaluating `DownValues[Subscript]`. You could use `TagSet` (shortcut: `/:`) to store that value in the `UpValues` of the localized `a`, which would behave as you expect (i.e. the rule in `UpValues` of `a` is removed when `Block` exits):

```
ClearAll[f, a, Subscript]
Subscript[f, i_][x_] := Block[{a},
  a /: Subscript[a, i] = 3 x;
  Subscript[a, 1]
]
```

on the other hand I wouldn't actually recommend to use such subscripted variables, what you have seen is probably only one of several unexpected things that could happen.

**Side Note**:It probably should be mentioned that the definition for `Subscript[f,i_][x_]` is also not associated with `f` but with `Subscript`, which can be checked by evaluating `SubValues[Subscript]`. Unfortunately this can not be changed by using `TagSet` for `f`, since Mathematica here will complain about `f` being too deep in the left hand side expression. One possibility to change that is to reformulate the function definition to e.g.:

```
f /: Subscript[f, i_] = Function[x,
  Block[{a},
   a /: Subscript[a, i] = 3 x;
   Subscript[a, 1]
   ]
  ]
```

which will behave the same as the original in most practical cases but of course is not exactly the same thing. You can use `UpValues[f]` to check that this rule is now really associated with `f`.

Comment: Actually, `DownValues[Subscript]` does not show anything, however `SubValues[Subscript]` does.

Comment: I think that depends on whether one evaluates `Subscript[f,1][2]` or `Subscript[f,1][2]=6`, as discussed elswhere...

Comment: Ah, I see. Then the answer needs to be clarified slightly, as there are no `DownValues` of `Subscript` associated with `f` (which is what I think you're answer implies) only `SubValues`, but there `DownValues` associated with `a`.

Comment: @rcollyer: I just added some additional remarks about downvalues, upvalues and subvalues. Hope this is now somewhat clearer.

Comment: You already had my +1, but thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to use `Module[]` instead of `Block[]`

```
Subscript[f, i_][x_] := Module[{a}, Subscript[a, i] = 3 x; Subscript[a, 1]]
```

Comment: Absolutely, but can you get the behavior with `Subscript[a,1]` that the OP is observing?

Comment: @rcollyer: Yes of course, it's even what I would expect :-). What are you observing and why would you think it should be different from what the OP writes?

Comment: Yes, if I post the OP's code into a fresh MMA session, I reproduce his issue, `Subscript[a,1]` returns `6` after an evaluation of `Subscript[f,1][2]`.  However, changing `Block[]` to `Module[]`, restarting the kernal and running the  notebook again yields the desired behavior, namely `Subscript[f,1][2] = 6` and `Subscript[a,1] = Subscript[a,1]`

Comment: @AlbertRetey I get `Subscript[a,1]` returned on v.8.0.4 with a fresh kernel.

Comment: @johntfoster: while that in a sense behaves like the OP wants, you would accumulate one rule per call to `Subscript[f,_][_]` in the downvalues of `Subscript` (evaluate `DownValues[Subscript]` to see what I'm talking about). This might not be a problem but could well become one when the function gets called frequently. Also there might be reasons to use `Block` instead of `Module`, they serve different purposes...

Comment: @rcollyer: you are right, I think the problem is that you correctly did evaluate `Subscript[f,1][2] = 6`, which will set a subvalue for `Subscript` with argument `f`, not a downvalue for `Subscript` with argument `a`. I didn't copy but retyped and evaluated just `Subscript[f,1][2]` and that then shows the behaviour that @Bee reported. @Bee: what exactly is it that you want to work?

Comment: @AlbertRetey retyped everything, and still getting the same behavior.

Comment: @rcollyer: sorry, it probably didn't become clear: the error was with me not with you. If you evaluate `Subscript[f,1][2] = 6` as the OP did post, then after that `Subscript[a,1]` will evaluate to itself, as you observed. If instead you evaluate just `Subscript[f,1][2]` (not setting it to 6), which is what I did, then after that `Subcript[a,1]` will evaluate to `6`, and this is because there is now an additional rule in the `DownValues` of `Subcript` which can be checked by evaluating `DownValues[Subscript]`. My guess is that the OP actually evaluated what I did and not what he posted...

Comment: @AlbertRetey thanks. I hadn't noticed the order problem. Likely that's exactly what happened, and the OP did not notice the order issue, either.

Comment: @rcollyer: I have now edited the question and made a note about that change.

Answer (score 4):

As [Albert Retey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3952/531) says, the issue is that

```
Subscript[a, i] = 3 x
```

affects the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DownValues.html) of `Subscript`, not any of the values of `a`. `Subscript` is one of the few system-defined symbols where you can modify its values without unprotecting it first (`Derivative` is another). Thus, in order to localize changes to subscripts of `a`, you need to use `Block` on `Subscript` instead of `a`. Thus, for your simple use case, you can do:

```
Subscript[h, i_][x_] := Block[{Subscript},
  Subscript[b, i] = 3 x;
  Subscript[b, i]]
```

Now things work as you want:

```
In[17]:= Subscript[h, 4][3]
Out[17]= 9

In[18]:= Subscript[b, 3]
Out[18]= Subscript[b, 3]
```

This has the drawback that you lose , because you lose all access to values of `Subscript` from outside the `Block`. For a somewhat contrived example of what can go wrong, consider:

```
Subscript[c, 1] = 17;

Subscript[hh, i_][x_] := Block[{Subscript},
  Subscript[b, i] = If[OddQ@Subscript[c, 1], 3 x, 4 x];
  Subscript[b, i]]

In[23]:= Subscript[hh, 4][17]
Out[23]= 68

In[24]:= OddQ@Subscript[c, 1]
Out[24]= True
```

This is perhaps not what you wanted to have happen. Now you can go ahead and manipulate things so that `Subscript` gets all the `DownValues` and `SubValues` from outside the `Block`, but this is an error-prone and likely inefficient hassle. However, there's an internal function that does exactly what you would want in this case, called [`Internal`InheritedBlock`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656):

```
Subscript[hhh, i_][x_] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{Subscript},
  Subscript[b, i] = If[OddQ@Subscript[c, 1], 3 x, 4 x];
  Subscript[b, i]]
```

Now you get the subscripts you want from outside without having to worry about clobbering anything:

```
In[31]:= Subscript[hhh, 4][17]
Out[31]= 51

In[32]:= Subscript[b, 3]
Out[32]= Subscript[b, 3]
```